# Clock input signal to the instances from the top module

Tags: verilog, clock

I have a top module ,everything it does is get inputs and outputs,define some wires and instantiate other modules.Every such module has a clock input.
I am wondering if I should define a clock in the top module and transfer it to each module it instantiates or should I transfer a clock parameter to top module also?

Comment: What do you mean by "should I transfer a clock parameter to top module also?"

Comment: I would go ahead and try to do whatever you are wanting to do. If it doesn't work, try something else. If you can't get it to work, come back and ask a question with all the details.

Answer (score 3):

It entirely depends on where you're sourcing the clock from, and what it does. On FPGA/CPLD designs (which I'm assuming you're working on), the clock will be obtained from a pin on the device. So, rather than "defining a clock", you'd grab it as an input in your top module, then connect it to each module it's required in.